# Why does "is" operator behave differently then expected, in `id(i) is id(j)`?

Tags: python

I know that the operators `is` and `is not` test for object identity: x is y is true if and only if x and y are the same object

> I initialize two variables `i` and `j` with the same value `10`, and when I am comparing the `id` of both variable with `is` operator it gives me a `False`
>   even though the `id(i)` and `id(j)` are the same.

I need a clarification, Here is my code

```
>>> i = 10;
>>> j = 10;
>>> print(10==10);
True
>>> print(id(10)==id(10));
True
>>> print(10 is 10);
True
>>> print(5+5 is 10);
True
>>> print(i == j);
True
>>> print(id(i) == id(j));
True
>>> print(i is j);
True
>>> print(id(i) is id(j)); # Why this statment Evaluate to False this is my quetion?
False
>>> id(i);
140718000878704
>>> id(j);
140718000878704
```

Comment: Possible duplication of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is

Comment: specifically this is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1085656/1240268 (small integers are cached and so the same object, large integers are not the same object)

Comment: Because you're confusing how to use `is`-operator. **Either you test `x is y` or you test `id(x) == id(y)`, but don't throw both into one expression: `id(x) is id(y)` makes no sense**: it would mean testing `id(id(x)) == id(id(y))`

Answer (score 1):

The `is` check is True if and only if the `id()`s are equal--if they are the *same object* in memory. (The `id()` builtin gets a unique integer identifier for the object, which is based on its memory address in CPython).

It is improper to use an `is` check on integers to compare their values. CPython does re-use integer objects in a small range instead of making new ones as an optimization, but this is an implementation detail that you should not rely upon.

For integer objects outside of that range, they may be separate objects in memory, even if they are equal in value.

For example,

```
>>> x = -6
>>> -6 is x
False
>>> x = 257
>>> 257 is x
False
```

Comment: @4nkit_patel That's because `-5` is inside that small range I mentioned where CPython re-uses the objects. That's why I used a `-6` :)

Comment: If I Do `>>> x = -5
>>> -5 is  x
True` this is true because you told CPython does re-use integer objects in a small range ??